# Teradata JDBC prepared statement error

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, teradata

When using Teradata 14 over JDBC I get the following SQL error for this SQL query bindings pair

query

```
"select regexp_instr('abc', 'a' || ?) s"
```

bindings

```
"bc"
```

error

```
 com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.JDBCException : [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 14.10.00.17] [Error 3536] [SQLState HY000] UPPERCASE or CASESPECIFIC specified for non-CHAR data.
```

When I execute the query directly with inline literals it works correctly.

Any ideas what does wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feedback from Teradata:

“Looks like this might be a bug in the Teradata Database". You can work around this by CASTing the character concatenation expression to VARCHAR.

```
 "select regexp_instr('abc', cast('a' || ? as varchar(100))) s"
```